# Access 2013 report background image not always showing

Tags: ms-access, pdf

So I am struggling with the following for quite some time. 
Iv'e got an Access front-end application that generates a few reports based on form data. The report has 1 background image that fills the entire background (a4 format).

With a click on the button the report is begin generated and converted to a PDF file using the build in Access PDF converter (`DoCmd.OutputTo 3, "", acFormatPDF`). What I do is:

1. I open the report
2. I use the OutputTo PDF.

Most of the times this works great, but for every 20 reports or so one goes wrong (being generated without an background-image).

After some research I found the following thread which exactly described my problem:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/background-image-sometim-t1998533.html

Several replies in this thread made me believe that the image just can't always be generated because it is perhaps to big. I believed the solution was to build in a delay with a DoEvents so that the report has enough time to generate the background.

I did this in the load event of the report:

```
Me.Picture = "O:\FactuurLayouts\VSP_Layout_NL_ENG.jpg" 'Setting the background


Dim sngStart As Single
DoCmd.Hourglass True 'Change cursor


sngStart = Timer ' Set start time.
Do While Timer < sngStart + 2 'wait for 2 seconds
DoEvents ' Yield to other processes.
Loop

DoCmd.Hourglass False
```

For some time it generated all the reports correctly so I thought the problem was solved, but sadly I had another empty one today.

Iv'e tried all the suggestions in the other thread but sadly none of them works.

Anyone has an idea what is causing this problem or perhaps a different way to get the background images in the reports?

**Some additional information**:

- The report is opened with a filter
- The background images have 3 variations, the first is 630kB in size,
  the second 1240kB and the third 389kB.
- All the background-images are JPG format.

Comment: Though much larger, try with pictures in the BMP format as this is read straight with no conversion.

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to work either, still blank background images.

Comment: Then you only option, I guess, is to try to reduce the size of the images by reducing colour count and resolution to a bare minimum. For a test and an extreme, create a simple B/W image of low resolution and see if this will fail.